# Is my proof by induction on binary trees correct?

Tags: logic, induction, trees

The following is an attempt to prove that a certain relation (4) holds, between the number of leaves, and *stems* in a **perfect** binary tree.

A *stem* will be defined as any node that has child nodes, and *leaves* those with none. For the purposes of this problem, each node can only have 2 or 0 children.

> I belive I have made a mistake in the inductive step. I re-used the
>   induction hypothesis after I obtained an equivalent formula for it. Here I
>   ask: Is this permitted?

In all equations, $S_n$ represents the number of stems, $L_n$ the number of leaves, and $n$ the height of the longest branch, starting from zero.

**Base Case**

When we have just one leaf node (a single dot), the relation (1) holds when n=0:

\begin{equation}\tag{1}
  S_n=L_n-1\ ,\ where\ L_n=2^n
\end{equation}

**Induction Hypothesis**

For an arbitrary but constant tree height, the relation $S_k=L_k-1\ ,\ where\ L_k=2^k$ is true.

**Inductive Step**

The act of changing $L_k$ end leaves to stems is the net effect bellow, which is equivalent to  $(+L_k)\ leaves$ and $(+L_k)\ stems$:

\begin{equation}
net\ effect = -L_k\ leaves \\
    \quad +L_k\ stems\\
    \quad +2L_k\ leaves.
\end{equation}

So the relations for each next step are $S_{k+1}=S_k+L_k$ and $L_{k+1}=L_k+L_k$ .

We want to see if (2) is true. Since $S_{k+1}=S_k+L_k$ and $L_{k+1}=L_k+L_k$ , (2) becomes (3) .

\begin{equation}\tag{2}
S_{k+1}=L_{k+1}-1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\tag{3}
S_k+L_k=L_k-1+L_k
\end{equation}

Since $L_k$ is added to both sides of (1), we can cancel and obtain our inductive hypothesis.

Now since the base case is true; and the inductive hypothesis implies the next configuration regardless of the starting configuration, it is implied that the relation bellow is true for all cases.

\begin{equation}\tag{4}
  S_n=L_n-1\ ,\ where\ L_n=2^n
\end{equation}

Comment: "that a certain relation holds" — namely? Without knowing what you try to prove, there is no way to tell whether your proof is correct.

Comment: @celtschk sorry, that 'certain relation' is the relation at the bottom of the post. Ill put it at the top as well for clarity.

Comment: How do you define $S_n$ and $L_n$? Can you please add that to your post?

Comment: Why are you assuming that the tree has constant height? This theorem is true even if the tree is "jagged", that is, not all branches has the same height. You should try proving this theorem for an arbitrary binary tree, with the assumption that each node has either 2 or 0 children. Then, induct on $n$, where $n$ is the height of the whole tree, that is, the length of the longest branch.

Comment: @MaudPieTheRocktorate Thanks for the tip, I didn't consider that the tree might be jagged.  I have changed the induction step to reflect the fact that the tree has arbitrary height and $n$ is the height of the longest branch.

Comment: First, you shouldn't assume $L_n=2^n$, since the tree can be jagged. Second, the notation of $S_n$ and $L_n$ are bad. $S_n$ makes it seem it only depends on $n$, but actually it depends on the tree $T$. I suggest you to change the notation to $S_T$ and $L_T$. And don't use $T_n$ to denote the tree, since the tree is not uniquely determined by $n$.

Comment: @MaudPieTheRocktorate Perhaps I should just turn it back into a tree in which the height each leaf is at is the same for all leaves. What I really want to know is the answer to my question highlighted in yellow. (I'm not concerned as much by the generality of this question)

Comment: @user400188 In that case, you should have said so in the beginning. You should have said that you are only studying [this kind of tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12359833).

Comment: @user400188 I cannot find what "equivalent formula" you meant. You only ever used $S_n=L_n-1$, no other equivalent formula found.

Comment: thank you. I wasn't sure on the terminology. Ill include it now to shorten and clarify the question. 
In regard of the "equivalent formula" it should be $S_k+x=L_k+x−1$ . Ill add that in too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simpler inductive proof:

**Induction start:** If the tree consists of only one node, that node is clearly a leaf, and thus $S=0$, $L=1$ and thus $S=L-1$.

**Induction hypothesis:** The claim is true for trees of less than $n$ nodes.

**Inductive step:** Let's assume we've got a tree of $n$ nodes, $n>1$. Then its root node obviously isn't a leaf, but a stem, and thus there are two sub-trees attached to it, both obviously with less than $n$ nodes. Therefore for these trees, we have $S_k = L_k-1$. Thus we have
$$S = 1 + S_l + S_r = 1 + (L_1-1) + (L_2-1) = L_1 + L_2 - 1 = L-1.$$

Answer (score 1):

A much easier method without using induction is by counting the number of arrows pointing from parent nodes to child nodes.

For the root node, it's the target of $0$ arrows, and the origin of $2$ arrows. For each non-root stem node, it is the target of $1$ arrow and the origin of $2$ arrows. For each leaf node, it's the target of $1$ arrow and the origin of $0$ arrows. Thus we have $$arrow = 2\times1+2\times (S-1) + 0\times L=0\times1+1\times (S-1)+1\times L$$
thus $S=L-1$

Comment: I have not! Check it carefully.

Comment: Ah, I see my mistake.